# Relation between Dirac function and inverse fourier transform of 1

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

According to my notes, it holds that $\delta=(2 \pi)^{-n} \widehat{1}$.

How do we get the equality?

We have that $\delta=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\delta}(\xi) e^{i x \xi} d{\xi}= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  e^{i x \xi} d{\xi}$.

But $\widehat{1}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i x \xi} d{x}$.

So how do we deduce that $\delta=(2 \pi)^{-n} \widehat{1}$?

Comment: Are you asking about the Fourier transform of the Dirac "function" (your title) or about its inverse Fourier transform (your text)?

Comment: I edited the title. @Did No, I am not asking about the Fourier transform of the Dirac "function" . I know how it can be shown that it is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition we have

$\displaystyle \langle \varphi, \widehat{\delta} \rangle= \langle \widehat{\varphi}, \delta \rangle = \widehat{\varphi}(0)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i x \cdot 0} \varphi(x)dx = (2\pi)^{-n/2} \langle \varphi , 1 \rangle$

by arbitrariness of $\varphi$ get the identity. Similary

$\displaystyle \langle \varphi, \widehat{1} \rangle = \langle \widehat{\varphi} , 1 \rangle = (2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i 0 \cdot \xi} \widehat{\varphi}(\xi) d \xi = (2\pi)^{n/2} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F} \varphi(0)=(2\pi)^{n/2}  \varphi(0)=(2\pi)^{n/2} \langle \varphi, \delta \rangle$

Note that you can also apply the inversion formula in the first identity. In this case there are the following definitions:

$\displaystyle \widehat{\varphi}(\xi):=(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-i x \cdot \xi} \varphi(x)dx$

$\displaystyle \mathcal{F}^{-1}\varphi(\xi):=(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i x \cdot \xi} \varphi(x)dx$

Comment: We have that $\widehat{\phi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x) e^{-i x \xi} dx$ and so $\widehat{\phi}(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x) dx$. Do you use an other definition?

Comment: It depends on how you define the Fourier transform. In this case $\widehat{\varphi}(\xi):= (2\pi)^{-n/2} \int \varphi(x) e^{-i x \cdot \xi} dx$.

Comment: I use the following definitions: $$\widehat{\phi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x) e^{-i x \xi} dx \\ \phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi}(\xi) e^{i x  \xi} d{\xi}$$

Using these definitions we get that $\langle \phi, \widehat{\delta} \rangle= \langle \phi, 1 \rangle$ and

$$\langle \phi, \widehat{1} \rangle= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi}(\xi) d{\xi}$$

Do we continue by substituting $\widehat{\phi}(\xi)$ ?

Comment: Is it right as follows? $$$$

$$\langle \phi, \widehat{1} \rangle= \langle \widehat{\phi},1 \rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi}(\xi) d{\xi}= \widehat{\widehat{\phi}}(0)=\phi(-0)=\phi(0)= \langle \delta, \phi \rangle$$

Comment: The technique used is always the same, note that $i 0 \cdot \xi =0$, and apply the inversion Fourier formula (calculated in 0). The fundamental identity is here: $(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i 0 \cdot \xi} \widehat{\varphi}(\xi) d \xi = (2\pi)^{n/2} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F} \varphi(0)$. I do not know how it is defined the inversion formula in your case

Comment: Is that what I wrote above wrong?  We have that $\langle \phi, \widehat{1} \rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi}(\xi) d{\xi}$. Why do we use the inverse Fourier formula?

Comment: We have defined it as I have written above:

$$\phi(x)= \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widehat{\phi}(\xi) e^{i x \xi} d{\xi}$$

Comment: I wrote the definitions in answers. You can then use the same technique with its definitions, it is not difficult, change only the constants.

Comment: So is that what I wrote right if we use the definitions that I know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40381/discussion-between-john-martin-and-evinda).

Answer (score 2):

Using that $\mathcal{F}\circ\mathcal{F}(f)(x)=f(-x)$ and in the comments you mentioned that you know that $\hat\delta =1$, we get
$$
 \hat 1 = \hat{\hat \delta} =\delta(-\cdot) =\delta
$$
with some normalizing coefficient depending on your Fourier transform.